# Connectedness of sub-varieties via Hilbert polynomials

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, hilbert-schemes

Let $X$ be a sub-variety of $\mathbb CP^n$ and let $p_X(k)$ be its Hilbert polynomial. It is well known that some basic invariants of $X$ (such as its dimension) can be read from $p_X(k)$. I am interested to know to which extent one can read connectedness of $X$ from $p_X(k)$.
Here are two precise questions. ($n$ is fixed).

**Question 1.** Is there a classification of polynomials, for which it is known that every subvariety in $\mathbb CP^n$ with given Hilbert polynomial is connected? If there is no such a classification, I would like at least to know a large list of such polynomials.

**Question 2.** Suppose that $P$ is the Hilbert polynomial of a complete intersection on $\mathbb CP^n$ of positive dimension. Is it true that any subscheme of $\mathbb CP^n$ with Hilbert polynomial $P$ is connected?

Answer (score 4):

Let me give a negative answer to Question 2, which shows that the answer to Question 1 should be almost always negative  (perhaps with very few exceptions).  The Hilbert polynomial of a complete intersection of type $(2,2)$ in $\mathbb{P}^3$  is $4k$. But this is also the Hilbert polynomial of the union of a plane quartic curve (embedded in $\mathbb{P}^3$) and two points lying anywhere in $\mathbb{P}^3$.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. It would be really curios then to see an approximate list of exceptions.

Comment: For curves in $\Bbb{P}^n$ I believe the only exceptions are indeed plane curves.